# The Siege of Jericho and the Seven Seals

Tags: revelation, joshua

Do the seven seals of the book of Revelation have an origin in the siege of Jericho?

This siege framework imagery can then be expounded upon, as with the seven seals, independently with the siege representing the day of the wrath. The day of wrath is the sacrifice of being made to be sin. It originates in Adam with the sword or Noah treading the wine press. Both start out in a barren land and both are found naked.

The simplified version:

- The first six marches/ The first six seals
- Seven marches on the seventh day/ Seven angels given seven trumpets
- The walls/ The scroll
- The people on both sides of the wall/ The writing on both sides of the scroll
- The seven priests / The seven angels
- The horns/ The trumpets
- The people are to be quiet/ Silence in heaven
- The people shout/ Loud voices in heaven

Relating the siege to the treading of the winepress of wrath;  "Faithful and True." He judges and wages war in righteousness. (Rev 19:11 NABO) The basic concept, to put it succinctly, and, literally: I (Resurrection) was Hitler (Sacrifice).

Comment: The question should include a specific verse that makes you think that there might be such a relationship.

Comment: Only inasmuch as if the seven vials are the seventh trumpet, and the sevent trumpets are the seventh seal.

Answer (score 2):

We have a series of striking verbal and structural parallels between the seven seals and the "Synoptic Apocalypse" as recorded in Matt 24, Mark 13 and Luke 21.

| Seal Description | Reference | Theme | Matthew | Mark | Luke |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. White Horse = Bow, crown, conquering conquest | Rev 6:1, 2 | Gospel progress | 24:13, 14 | 13:10, 11, 13 | 21:15, 18, 19 |
| 2. Red Horse = Take Peace, men kill each other, large sword | Rev 6: 3, 4 | War | 24:6, 7, 21 | 13:7, 8 | 21:9, 10, 24 |
| 3. Black Horse = Scales in hand, measuring out very expensive food | Rev 6:5, 6 | famine | 24:7 | 13:8 | 21:11 |
| 4. Pale green Horse Death & Hades follow, kill by sword, famine, plague, wild beasts | Rev 6:7, 8 | Pestilence | 24:7 | 13:8 | 21:11 |
| 5. Souls under the Altar = “How long . . . until you judge?” told to wait a little longer | Rev 6:9-11 | Persecution, Vengeance, Delay | 24:6-10 | 13:9 | 21:9, 12, 13, 22 |
| 6. Great Earthquake etc | Rev 6:12-7:14 | Earthquakes; / Sun moon & Stars; / nations distressed; / Who can stand?? / Angels gather elect; /Tribulation. | 24:7; 24:29; 24:21, 30; — ; 24:31; 24:10, 21, 22. | 13:8; 13:24, 25; 13:19; — ; / 13:27; / 13:19. | 21:11; / 21:25, 26; / 21:23, 25, 26; / 21:36; / — ; / 21:23, 24. |
| 7 Silence in Heaven | Rev 8:1 | ?? | -- | -- | -- |

Therefore, I see far greater parallels between Jesus' apocalyptic sermon, than with the fall of Jericho.

Comment: I would suggest that the first row is incorrect.  Rather than "Gospel progress", the white horse should represent a "false Gospel" that has spread throughout Christendom (when the real Christ later appears, he also is riding a white horse). ¶ i.e. change Matthew 24:13,14 → 24:4,5;
Mark 13:10,11,13 → 13:5,6;
and Luke 21:15,18,19 → 21:8.
¶ This interpretation is also a better fit as in each Gospel the four horsemen are then listed consecutively, in the same order as in Revelation.

Comment: Since my comment could be considered negative, and it's no longer obvious now, mine was the up-vote, not the no-reason-given down-vote.

Comment: The sixth seal is the signs of and preparation for what is about to occur (e.g. Mat 24:15–20).
The seventh seal is the seven trumpets, which form the great tribulation (e.g. Mat 24:21–22).
¶ See the [The Seals of the Prophetic Scroll](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/the-book-of-revelation-unveiled/the-seals-of-the-prophetic-scroll) chapter of [The Book of Revelation Unveiled | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/the-book-of-revelation-unveiled) for one denomination's interpretation of this.

Comment: @RayButterworth - many thanks - the reason I suggest the "Gospel progress" was the (1) the use of white as a universal color or righteousness in the NT; (2) comparison with the rider on the white horse in Rev 19; (3) similarities with Matt 24, etc.

Comment: Jesus’ body is the temple with not one stone left standing on another; the abomination of desolation is in him at the resurrection from his sacrifice. When asked when his coming will be he said, Mt 24:3; there will be wars and rumors of wars but the sacrifice of being made to be sin is when he comes on the day of wrath. The Fig tree is Christianity, which he planted. Finding no fruit at his return from the day of wrath, he curses it, it is cut down and removed from the soil. {The notes in my 1976 NAB for Catholics claims Judaism is the Fig Tree. If you are wondering where I got the idea from}